# UITableViewCell not showing checkmark accessory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that gets shown when a button is tapped and it should display a checkmark accessory on a cell which is determined using a specific string from an array (the array that populates the table view) based on its index. I have the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[arrayOfSounds indexOfObject:currentSound]];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewProperty cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];`

but some why it doesn't display the proper checkmark.
The `currentSound` variable is a string and it does have the correct text as I checked during debugging. Please advise!

Comment: Where is this code being executed?  Is it in a delegate method for UITableView or somewhere else?

Comment: @JuJoDi it is being executed in the `viewDidLoad` method of a subclass of `UITableViewController` and `tableViewProperty` points to the table view in the Interface Builder where this class is the delegate and dataSource of the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the tableView's

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

to reload the cell.